# Continuity and bounds proof (stuck because of signs)

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is continuous at $c$, I want to show that if $v\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(c)<v$ (***note: it actually says $f(x)<v$ but I think it is a typo***) the $\exists\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta),\ f(x)<v$

This is just continuity re-written really ($x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)\iff c-\delta<x<c+\delta\iff -\delta<x-c<\delta \iff |x-c|<\delta$)

So we know $\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0:|x-c|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$

So I tried picking $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}|f(c)-v|$ but didn't get anywhere. I'm stuck because of the signs $v$ and $f(c)$ might take. $v$ could be quite a large positive number $f(c)$ my confidence for $\epsilon$ fades a little.

I want to show it "the hard way" (considering $f(c)<v$ not $g(x)=f(x)-v<0)$ because this is from before the proof that the sum of continuous functions is continuous in the book, so I should be able to do it without. It is after sequential continuity, but I'd rather not.

Comment: Could you provide a reference where you found the problem?

Answer (score 0):

By using your choice of $\delta$ and $\epsilon$:

$$f(x) = f(x)+f(c)-f(c)+v-v = v + (f(c)-v) + (f(x)-f(c)) $$$$\le v + (f(c)-v) + |f(x)-f(c)| < v + (f(c)-v) + \frac 12 |f(c)-v |$$
$$=v+\frac 12 (f(c)-v) +\frac 12 ( (f(c)-v)  +   |f(c)-v | ).$$

Now the second term is negative by assumption and the third one is $y+|y|$ for $y= \frac 12   (f(c)-v)$, which is zero because $y<0$.

Comment: I don't quite follow that last bit. Was I right?

Comment: @AlecTeal Right about what? |Your choice of $\epsilon$ is ok. After that, where exactly do you have troubles in this proof?

Comment: Oh I see! the middle term is negative by assumption (as you said) but that last term is not zero, I'm not sure where you get the zero or $y+|y|$

Comment: @AlecTeal thel ast term is $\frac 12 ( (f(c)-v)  +   |f(c)-v | )$. Since $(f(c)-v)<0$, we can rewrite $|f(c)-v|=v-f(c)$, so the sum is $\frac 12 ( (f(c)-v)  +   |f(c)-v | ) = \frac 12 ( (f(c)-v)  +   v-f(c) )=0$.